# HTML <a href> to open Excel docuemnt - Specific worksheet

Tags: javascript, html, excel-2010

I have a problem when trying to reference a *Specific* worksheet within an excel using a ref in HTML.

```
<a href="ExcelFileNAme.xltm">\ <!--- works !--->
```

The below doesn't work when referencing the worksheet.

```
<a href="ExcelFileNAme.xltm#worksheetname">\
```

Is there a solution to this, using HTML or JScript without creating xx seperate excel files for accessing each worksheet directly?

If it is possible, is it also possible to hide all the other worksheet pages if the browser ahref points to worksheet1... worksheet 2-n should be hidden.

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: did you try to give cell reference to this worksheet like `file.xlsx#worksheetname!A1`

Answer (score 0):

Give cell reference

```
<a href="ExcelFileNAme.xltm#worksheetname!A1>
```

Comment: Tried this doesn't seem to work. Do I need to define name a cell.. im usring the tab page name that ive renamed to whatever and incldued !A1 but it can't find the file... Only finds it if I open it as a file without a sheet reference